# How to get list of application which are maintain history data?

Tags: android, web-applications, browser-history

I am Developing an Application, in that `i have to show a list which applications are showing the history or maintain the previous data`  like `Browsers and whatsapp, wechat...` . is there any `intent action` or use full  method in android API.

thank you for helping.

Comment: i am also searching for same problem, thank you for posting question @balaji koduri

Answer (score 0):

> is there any intent action or use full method in android API

No. App developers do not have to tell other app developers whether their app is "showing the history" or can "maintain the previous data".

> i have to show a list which applications are showing the history or maintain the previous data

Since almost all apps "maintain the previous data" (e.g., game high scores, blood pressure readings, to-do items), simply list all applications.